# Can't get 1680x1050 resolution with Macbook Pro ~2009 and Snow Leopard

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, display, vga-adapter

I have a Late 2009 Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard (with all updates installed).

I have started my move from Windows to OS X as my everyday computing platform and I am trying to connect my external Samsung Monitor (that was used with Windows) to Macbook Pro using the mini DisplayPort to VGA connector.

For the life of me, I can't get OS X to set the monitor's native resolution of 1680x1050 setup. When the external display is auto-detected, the resolution is set up as 800x600.

I have tried using two different mini DisplayPort to VGA connectors and separate VGA cable to rule out the connector/cable issue. The monitors work fine as I have been using them with Windows 8 and they work perfectly fine (all autodectected).

My monitor's native resolution is 1680x1050 at 60Hz.

Comment: The exact monitor type might help get answers here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably the VGA adapter (not faulty; just not capable of that high a resolution).  I think you need a [DVI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A?fnode=53) to get the higher resolutions.

Comment: Oops - 3 weeks old question.  Answer still stands.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/527192/120614 suggests VGA should be fine for this resolution.

Comment: And I've now successfully driven a monitor at 1680x1050@60Hz with an Early 2013 MacBook Pro over VGA, so it's not the VGA cable.